# Relation between sum and cardinality of finite set

Tags: summation

Let $A$ be a finite set with cardinality $\lvert A\rvert$. Then is it true that $\sum_{j\in A}1 =\lvert A\rvert$?

Comment: What does that $\sum_{j\in A_{k}}$ even mean...

Comment: The title suggests that you're allowing some of the $A_i$s to be empty, but in a partition all pieces are usually required to be nonempty (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set)). Note meanwhile that the only sensible value for the "empty sum" $\sum_{i\in\emptyset}1$ is $0$ (we'll want $(\sum_{i\in A}1)+(\sum_{j\in B}1)=\sum_{k\in A\cup B}1$ whenever $A\cap B=\emptyset$); similarly, the"empty product" $\prod_{i\in\emptyset}1$ should be $1$.

Comment: @ArcticChar I suspect that's supposed to be "$\sum_{j\in A_k}1$."

Comment: @ArcticChar To be understood as $\sum_{j\in A_{k}}1$.

Comment: We don’t need to know what the $A_k$ are, other than that they’re finite sets.  $\sum_{j\in A} 1 = |A|$ always.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @mjqxxxx Fixed now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer - surprisingly, I couldn't find a duplicate of this question on this site, although I vividly recall it being asked before:*

The answer is **yes**. For finite $A$s this is obvious; the interesting question is what happens when $A$ is empty:

> What is the value of the "empty sum" $\sum_{i\in\emptyset}1$?

The answer (ignoring a minority of authors who require the index set of a sum to be nonempty) is that the empty sum equals $0$. This is more than merely a convention - it is the **only possible** way to define the empty sum which is at all reasonable. Specifically, one of the key rules about summations is that $$\sum_{i\in A}f(i)+\sum_{j\in B}f(j)=\sum_{k\in A\cup B}f(k)$$ whenever $A\cap B=\emptyset$ (ignoring issues around definedness, e.g. problems with conditional convergence - if you like, require $f$ to only ever output nonnegative values). Since $\emptyset\cap B=\emptyset$ for all $B$ we'll want $$\sum_{i\in\emptyset}f(i)+x=x$$ for all $x$ and $f$, and this pins down the value of the empty sum.

Similarly, the "empty product" $\prod_{i\in\emptyset}1$ is $1$. This is an instance of a more general phenomenon: that "natural" operations often come equipped with overarching properties which yield canonical extensions to larger-than-originally-considered domains (e.g. extending the summation operation from nonempty index sets to include the empty set).

Answer (score 1):

The identity
$$
\sum_{j\in A} 1 =\lvert A\rvert
$$
is correct since
you are adding a one for every value of $j$ present in the set $A$, which in this case is equivalent to the cardinality of $A$.

Comment: Note however that as far as I'm aware the notation "$\sum_{j\in A}$" is nonstandard; in fact, I've never seen it used.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I have used this notation before without any confusion. The notation under the uppercase sigma is simply directions of what to sum over, which from the context given in the question is clear. It is very similar to the notation under an integral sign when integrating over a set too.

Comment: Fair, I'm a bit surprised. But would you really write $\int_A$ instead of $\int_Adx$ (keeping in mind that "$dx$" should be conflatable with "$1dx$," thinking either about forms or Riemann sums)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber No I would definitely write $\int_A \mathrm dx$ that's why you need to include the variable of summation in this case, i.e. $\sum_{j\in A}$ instead of $\sum_{A}$. Maybe I am misunderstanding you.